# Sign Up with Google authentication in Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

As it says in the title, I have trouble with Google authentication in my Android app.
The problem is that when I run the app and sign up with my own Google account, everything's fine there, I can sign up with my Google account, but other people cannot sign up, I don't know why, they push the button "Sign in for Google" and the system asks them which account the want to sign up with, but then nothing happens.

The code its already in production by the way.

How can I fix this in order that other people can sign up with a Google account?

```
// [START config_signin]
        // Configure Google Sign In
        GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();

        mGoogleSignInClient = GoogleSignIn.getClient(this, gso);
        // [END config_signin]

        onGoogle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                signIn();
            }
        });
    }
    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (mAuthProvider.getUserSession() != null){
            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,HomeActivity.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    }

    // [START onactivityresult]
    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        // Result returned from launching the Intent from GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(...);
        if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
            Task<GoogleSignInAccount> task = GoogleSignIn.getSignedInAccountFromIntent(data);
            try {
                // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
                GoogleSignInAccount account = task.getResult(ApiException.class);
                Log.d(TAG, "firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + account.getId());
                firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account.getIdToken());
            } catch (ApiException e) {
                // Google Sign In failed, update UI appropriately
                Log.w(TAG, "Google sign in failed", e);
            }
        }
    }
    // [END onactivityresult]

    // [START auth_with_google]
    private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(String idToken) {
        mDialog.show();
        mAuthProvider.googleLogin(idToken).addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                            String id = mAuthProvider.getUid();
                            checkUserExist(id);
                            // Sign in success, update UI with the signed-in user's information
                            /*Log.d(TAG, "signInWithCredential:success");
                            Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                            startActivity(intent);*/

                        } else {
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            // If sign in fails, display a message to the user.
                            Log.w(TAG, "signInWithCredential:failure", task.getException());

                        }
                    }
                });
    }

    private void checkUserExist(String id) {
        mUsersProvider.getUser(id).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(DocumentSnapshot documentSnapshot) {
                if (documentSnapshot.exists()){
                    mDialog.dismiss();
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, HomeActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }
                else {
                    String email = mAuthProvider.getEmail();
                    User user = new User();
                    user.setEmail(email);
                    user.setId(id);
                    mUsersProvider.create(user).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                            mDialog.dismiss();
                            if (task.isSuccessful()){
                                Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, CompleteProfileActivity.class);
                                startActivity(intent);
                            }else Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Erro al crear usuario", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                }
            }
        });
    }
    // [END auth_with_google]
```

Comment: Or do You think this problem is with my firebase project?